# Animate row additions/reloads/deletions in paginated UITableView with ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reactive-cocoa, ios-animations

I have a paginated `tableView` with 2 tabs at the top, Latest and Popular, and I can't get it to animate model changes properly with `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]`.

There are 3 loading modes for the `tableView`:

- `LoadingModeRefresh`: when the user refreshes with pull to refresh.
- `LoadingModeNewPage`: when the user reaches the end of the `tableView` so that a new page needs to be loaded
- `LoadingModeNewTab`: when the user changes the tab at the top

I receive 30 items per page from the backend (for pagination)

Also I have a loading cell at the end of the `tableView` so that when someone reaches to the end of the table, he/she can see that it's loading, and when new data arrives, that loading cell is pushed to the end of the `tableView`, out of sight.

The behaviour I want is as follows:

- When the user pulls to refresh, 30 new items are fetched and are set as the backing model for the `tableView`, and the `tableView` should reload items from 0 to 29, and delete the rest since the user might have paged more than 1 page so there might be more than 30 items before the refresh, hence we need to delete the extra items after the refresh.
- When the user reaches the end of the table, 30 new items are fetched and are appended to the end of the backing model for the `tableView`, and we should insert those 30 rows to the `tableView`.
- When the user switches tabs, I first want the `tableView` to be cleared of all the cells so that the loading cell I mentioned is the only cell. so I set the backing model of the `tableView` to an empty array, and remove all the rows from the `tableView`. after 30 new items are fetched I insert those 30 rows to the `tableView`.

I have 3 properties on my `ViewModel` representing changes to indexPaths: `indexPathsToDelete`, `indexPathsToInsert` and `indexPathsToReload`, which are bound to changes in the backing model with `-[RACSignal combinePrevious:reduce:]`. My view controller observes these properties, zips them together and applies the changes at once. however somehow my fetching code is being called twice, which causes the indexPaths to be calculated and observed more than once, which causes inconsistencies with the `tableView` and causes crashes. Can anyone help with where the problem is, since I can not seem to understand what's happening?

here is the code for the `ViewModel` (sorry for the code, haven't refactored it yet since I haven't got it to work yet):

```
const NSInteger kArticlePerPage = 30;

@interface FeedViewModel ()

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) Source *model;
@property (nonatomic) LoadingMode loadingMode;

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger selectedTabIndex;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger pagesRequested;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger pagesLoaded;

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSArray *indexPathsToDelete;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSArray *indexPathsToInsert;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSArray *indexPathsToReload;

- (NSArray *)indexPathsForRange:(NSRange)range inSection:(NSInteger)section;

@end

@implementation FeedViewModel

- (instancetype)initWithModel:(Source *)source
{
    self = [super init];

    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    _model = source;
    _pagesLoaded = 0;

    RACSignal *loadingModeSignal = RACObserve(self, loadingMode);
    RACSignal *newTabSignal = [loadingModeSignal  //
        filter:^BOOL(NSNumber *loadingMode) {
            return loadingMode.integerValue == LoadingModeNewTab;
        }];
    RACSignal *newPageSignal = [loadingModeSignal  //
        filter:^BOOL(NSNumber *loadingMode) {
            return loadingMode.integerValue == LoadingModeNewPage;
        }];
    RACSignal *refreshSignal = [loadingModeSignal  //
        filter:^BOOL(NSNumber *loadingMode) {
            return loadingMode.integerValue == LoadingModeRefresh;
        }];

    RAC(self, loading) = [loadingModeSignal  //
        map:^id(NSNumber *loadingMode) {
            switch (loadingMode.integerValue) {
                case LoadingModeFinished:
                    return @(NO);

                default:
                    return @(YES);
            }
        }];

    @weakify(self);

    RACSignal *newArticlesSignal = [[[[RACSignal
        combineLatest:@[ RACObserve(self, pagesRequested), RACObserve(self, selectedTabIndex) ]]
        sample:RACObserve(self, loadingMode)]  //
        map:^id(RACTuple *tuple) {
            @strongify(self);
            return [self signalForNewArticlesForPage:tuple.first order:[tuple.second integerValue]];
        }]  //
        switchToLatest];

    RACSignal *articlesForNewTabSignal = [[newTabSignal  //
        flattenMap:^RACStream * (id value) {             //
            return [newArticlesSignal startWith:@[]];
        }]  //
        skip:1];

    RACSignal *articlesForNewPageSignal = [newPageSignal  //
        flattenMap:^RACStream * (id value) {
            return [newArticlesSignal  //
                map:^id(NSArray *newArticles) {
                    @strongify(self);

                    Article *article = self.articles[0];
                    NSLog(@"article name: %@", article.title);
                    return [self.articles arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:newArticles];

                }];
        }];
    RACSignal *articlesForRefreshSignal = [refreshSignal  //
        flattenMap:^RACStream * (id value) {              //
            return newArticlesSignal;
        }];

    RAC(self, articles) = [RACSignal merge:@[
        articlesForNewTabSignal,   //
        articlesForNewPageSignal,  //
        articlesForRefreshSignal
    ]];


    RACSignal *articlesSignal = RACObserve(self, articles);

    RAC(self, indexPathsToDelete) = [articlesSignal  //
        combinePreviousWithStart:@[]                 //
                          reduce:^id(NSArray *previous, NSArray *current) {
                              @strongify(self);
                              if (previous.count > current.count) {
                                  return [self
                                      indexPathsForRange:NSMakeRange(current.count,
                                                                     previous.count - current.count)
                                               inSection:0];
                              }
                              else {
                                  return @[];
                              }
                          }];

    RAC(self, indexPathsToInsert) = [articlesSignal                          //
        combinePreviousWithStart:@[]                                         //
                          reduce:^id(NSArray *previous, NSArray *current) {  //
                              @strongify(self);
                              if (previous.count < current.count) {
                                  return [self
                                      indexPathsForRange:NSMakeRange(previous.count,
                                                                     current.count - previous.count)
                                               inSection:0];
                              }
                              else {
                                  return @[];
                              }
                          }];

    RAC(self, indexPathsToReload) = [articlesSignal  //
        combinePreviousWithStart:@[]                 //
                          reduce:^id(NSArray *previous, NSArray *current) {
                              if (previous.count >= current.count) {
                                  return [self indexPathsForRange:NSMakeRange(0, current.count)
                                                        inSection:0];
                              }
                              else {
                                  return @[];
                              }
                          }];

    RAC(self, pagesLoaded) = [[RACObserve(self, articles)  //
        skip:1]                                            //
        map:^id(NSArray *array) {                          //
            NSInteger pages = array.count / kArticlePerPage;
            if (array.count % kArticlePerPage != 0) {
                pages++;
            }
            return @(pages);
        }];


    RAC(self, separatorColorHexString) = [RACObserve(self, model.type) map:^id(NSNumber *type) {
        if (type.integerValue == SourceTypeInspiration) {
            return @"ffffff";
        }
        else {
            return @"E5E5E5";
        }
    }];

    RAC(self, segmentTitles) = [RACObserve(self, model)  //
        map:^id(Source *source) {

            NSMutableArray *titles = [NSMutableArray array];

            if (source.isPopularAvailable) {
                [titles addObject:@"Popular"];
            }

            if (source.isLatestAvailable) {
                [titles addObject:@"Latest"];
            }

            return titles;
        }];
    return self;
}

- (void)setCurrentSource:(Source *)source
{
    self.model = source;
}

- (void)refreshCurrentTab
{
    self.pagesRequested = 1;
    self.loadingMode = LoadingModeRefresh;
}

- (void)requestNewPage
{
    if (self.pagesRequested == self.pagesLoaded + 1) {
        return;
    }

    self.pagesRequested = self.pagesLoaded + 1;
    self.loadingMode = LoadingModeNewPage;
}

- (void)selectTabWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    self.selectedTabIndex = index;
    self.pagesRequested = 1;
    self.loadingMode = LoadingModeNewTab;
}

- (void)selectTabWithIndexIfNotSelected:(NSInteger)index
{
    if (self.selectedTabIndex == index) {
        return;
    }

    [self selectTabWithIndex:index];
}

- (NSArray *)indexPathsForRange:(NSRange)range inSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSMutableArray *indexes = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSUInteger i = range.location; i < range.location + range.length; i++) {
        [indexes addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section]];
    }

    return [indexes copy];
}

- (RACSignal *)signalForNewArticlesForPage:(NSNumber *)pageNumber order:(ArticleOrder)order
{
    return [[SourceManager sharedManager] articlesForSourceKey:self.model.key
                                                  articleOrder:order
                                                    pageNumber:pageNumber];
}

- (void)setLoadingMode:(LoadingMode)loadingMode
{
    _loadingMode = loadingMode;
}

@end
```

and the code for observing indexPath arrays in `ViewController.m`:

```
RACSignal *toDeleteSignal = [RACObserve(self, viewModel.indexPathsToDelete)  //
    deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]];                           //

RACSignal *toInsertSignal = [RACObserve(self, viewModel.indexPathsToInsert)  //
    deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]];                           //

RACSignal *toReloadSignal = [RACObserve(self, viewModel.indexPathsToReload)  //
    deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]];

[[RACSignal zip:@[ toDeleteSignal, toInsertSignal, toReloadSignal ]]
    subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *tuple) {

        @strongify(self);

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tuple.first
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tuple.second
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:tuple.third
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];

        if (self.tableView.pullToRefresh.state == BPRPullToRefreshStateLoading) {
            [self.tableView.pullToRefresh dismiss];
        }

    }];
```

Other than that, I only call `[self.viewModel requestNewPage]` when `tableView:willDisplayCell:` is called for the last cell in the tableView, `[self.viewModel selectTabWithIndexIfNotSelected:index]` when the segment selection changes. `[self.viewModel selectTabWithIndex:0]` in viewDidLoad and `[self.viewModel refreshCurrentTab]` in the refresh handler.

Where am I making a mistake?